# Temporary Table - Maximum allowed number of 1000 row values

Tags: sql-server, limit, temporary

When trying to insert 6000 rows into a temp table I get the following message

> The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds
>   the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

Source is not located in `SQL Server`.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP_ISIN (
   [Isin] nVARCHAR(250))

INSERT INTO #TMP_ISIN ([Isin])
VALUES
ABOUT 6000 ROWS
```

How shall I do to avoid this limit?

Answer (score 15):

The [limit of 1000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) is on the number of rows in the `values` clause of the `insert` rather than a limitation of the temporary table itself:

> **The maximum number of rows that can be constructed by inserting rows directly in the VALUES list is 1000.** Error 10738 is returned if the number of rows exceeds 1000 in that case.
>
> To insert more than 1000 rows, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Create multiple INSERT statements;
> - Use a derived table;
> - Bulk import the data by using the `bcp` utility or the `BULK INSERT` statement.

Hence you can do it in chunks, with smaller `insert` statements.

```
insert into sometable (somecolumns) values <about 1000 rows>;
insert into sometable (somecolumns) values <about 1000 rows>;
:
insert into sometable (somecolumns) values <about 1000 rows>;
```

If you need all 6000 to be atomic, you can put a transaction around the whole thing.

Answer (score 5):

It’s *very* easy to get around this limitation by using what Microsoft refers to as a **Derived Table**:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test;
CREATE TABLE #test(
    id integer identity(1,1) primary key,
    name varchar(48),
    etc varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO #test(name,etc)
SELECT * FROM (     --  add this line
VALUES
    ('apple','Red round thing with a worm in it.'),
    ('banana','Long yellow thing to feed monkeys.'),
    ('cherry','Small black thing for cocktails.')
    --  thousands more rows
) AS whatever(a,b)  --  add this line
;
```

The code is similar to the `INSERT … VALUES …`, but copies the values from a virtual derived table.

As you see, the alias for the `VALUES` is `whatever`, and both the alias and the columns are arbitrary; they do not affect the data copy in any way.

The solution comes indirectly from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause .

Seriously I cannot see why Microsoft impose this idiotic limit of 1000 rows for an INSERT statement if it’s so easy to work around it.

I guess it’s a Microsoft thing … 1000 rows ought to be enough for anyone.

Answer (score 2):

It's only an issue with the `VALUES` clause. If you're inserting more than 1000 rows by this method (questionable approach but hey) then use a set of `SELECT` statements with `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT #a (a,b)
SELECT 'a', 'b' UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'd' UNION ALL
SELECT ...etc
```

This also has the advantage that you can check the resultset from the `SELECT` statements prior to doing the `INSERT`s - you won't get that luxury with the `VALUES` construct.