# SQL Server 50000 insert too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a load of data which consists of only 2 columns as 50000 rows in MS Excel. I created an insert query using some concat() functions and got a list of insert queries (additional info in file:
[image]

```
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14878, 1000009442)
```

However, when I try to run the insert statements, it inserts only 50-60 rows per minute, which I would argue is extremely slow.

Note that there is no single index, column or any sort of handicap in the table.

Which steps should I take to analyze why this happens? Or if have any direct answer, which you may have already encountered, please, let me know the solution.

Comment: Please don't kill kittens. Read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Try adding `BEGIN TRAN` at the beginning and `COMMIT` at the end so they aren't all running as individual transactions, though it still sounds woefully slow for individual transactions too TBH

Comment: Which client software are you using to insert the rows? Is it configured to autocommit? If it is not autocommit I recommend adding a `commit` statement every N rows to see if it improves. between, 50/60 rows per minute is still too slow even in the case of a single session.

Comment: Hi all. i am using SSMS 18  for this. @MartinSmith I tried it , but no advantage so far.

Comment: @JorgeCampos client software is ssms 18 , commiting at the end of every transaction or every N rows did not work for me.  Maybe there is some config of db which makes it so slow. Not sure

Comment: Does the table have any triggers? When you gather the execution plan for a single insert that takes a second what wait types are there?

Comment: It's possible to share a sample portion of the excel file?

Comment: @MartinSmith nothing , just plain table freshly created . single insert is just fine with table insert , compute scalar  and constant scan

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur here is the link  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13iWVUN9eK36CDC0aM7RzzHooZkVGJjff/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=110288121653662084438&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I've tried your queries, it takes 9 seconds to insert 50k rows. It have to be some sort of hardware issue on your server, probably with hard disk. Maybe network.

Comment: Is the table you're inserting into in use by other queries at the same time? it could be a locking issue. Try inserting into a variable table / temp table or simply into a whole different table and see if it performs the same. Afterwards, insert from your "staging" table into the final table and see if it improves. I would also recommend batching the insert with 1000 rows at once (instead of 1 by 1).

Comment: Did you check the topics related to network and hard drive?can you show your execution plan? Why didn't you use bulk insert?

Comment: @FAB tried both table variable and temp tables (both session and global) . nothing changed . regarding 1000 batch size , I tried even 100 , but nothing changed.

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi you might have said something I did not consider. The only thing I checked is log db size which is configured autoscale . execution plan is simple as table insert , compute scalar and constant scan - these are normal insert stages I believe. Regarding bulk insert , I dont have access to the server where db is installed.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic thanks for noting these . I also suspect it , but not sure why this even happened considering no change is carried out recently. Yeap , this is like a black box.

Comment: The execution plan contains information about wait types. What does that show?

Answer (score 0):

It took seconds to insert all the rows on my local PC.

In the c column of the Excel sheet, I have written this formula:

```
="insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) values ("&A1&", "&B1&");"
```

I got these SQL statements:

```
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14878,1000009442);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14867,1000001802);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14876,1000004098);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14796,1000000673);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14932,1000009255);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14831,1000011692);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14977,1000002093);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14721,1000004031);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14759,1000005564);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14796,1000002776);
insert into X_Table (Id, NewId) 
values (14706,1000005490);
```

All 50'000 rows have been inserted within 6 seconds. Please try this.

Comment: in my local db the same occurs. However, I have got another dev env which I need to insert . How do I check what are the differences that cause this issue?

Comment: One big `INSERT...VALUES...` is almost certainly going to be faster

Comment: I didn't do that. But tried after seeing your message and got following error: `The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.`

Comment: Yeah you need to do `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM (VALUES...` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68634230/14868997 although `BULK INSERT` or a Table Valued Parameter is certainly even faster.